My 1999 grand Marquis won’t accelerate over 30?
My 1999 grand Marquis Won’t accelerate over 30. We have changed the fuel filter and pump, gas tank, spark plugs, mass air flow sensor, checked catalytic converter, coil packs. Still running the same. What else could it be? I’m thinking transmission maybe?

The check engine light is on, right? What are the fault codes? You can read them yourself using a code reader or go to an auto parts store, which usually will read codes for free. Please write down the exact codes and edit your question to include them.

You should check the transmission fluid level and condition.

A damaged catcon can strangle exhaust flow. Tried removing the upstream O2 sensors before the catcon? A drive around the block may reveal it if engine power is suddenly restored.
